# How can an event handler be wired up when using an ASP.NET Core Web API Controller which is raising events?

Tags: c#, events, asp.net-core, event-handling, asp.net-core-webapi

Basically I don't even know where to register an event handler at the controller instance, because instantiation is handled by the DI container and I'd like to register at the newly created controller instance.

Is this even advisable to do, or is there a better way which fits the architecture of ASP.NET Core?

The scenario is this:
A hidden link is available to some anonymous user until an expiry date.

First use case:
Any anonymous user can manually "close" the link (make it invalid/unavailable) using a Web API call to a controller method.
This method could raise an OnLinkClosed event.

Second use case:
A "chron job" checks the hidden links database table and if one expired it will set the entry to "closed" (instead of a user). It might call a differnt API function (i.e. because now we know who/what closed the link) but the reaction to it is basically the same.
This could raise an OnLinkClosedByChronJob event.

Reacting to OnLinkClosed, OnLinkClosedByChronJob:

- The link data in the DB needs to be flagged as closed.
- Some data needs to checked and the original creator (who ist known) of the hidden link needs to be informed via e-mail.
- (Maybe a SignalR broadcast needs to happen.)
- (Maybe some statistics need updating.)

I don't want to hard code all this (and later) functionality in the controller method (to avoid long controller methods would be one concern). Maybe I should do it in a service!? I'm not so sure yet of when to place code in the controller method or into a service. (Except when I need the service functionality in more than one controller, obviously. Any hints/articles covering this topic are appreciated.)
I don't necessarily want to use MediatR or the functional approach (see here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IROSd7uB-tg&t=35m11s) but it may be what I'm looking for.

At best I want to do all/some of the reaction functionality asynchronously or even in parallel.

An event like "this link got closed - anyone interested?" seemed to be a viable idea.

Comment: I would reconsider this. Can you describe your use case a bit more? Who would be the subscriber?

Comment: @Stefan I tried to describe the intended use case. Subscribers would be the instances dealing with the subtasks. (But as described - maybe I'm thinking in the wrong direction.)

Comment: I see. I think you should drop the idea of an event on this level. Controllers are created on a http-request basis. The live on different threads. This can cause all kinds of complexities. An action by itself already is an "event", or request. As for now, I think you should code your code in the controller or in a service. Try to work to a minimal proof of concept. If you run into questions/issues, you can always ask for help.

Comment: @Pascal Did you ever find out the way to this? I'm curious but can't quite work it out at the moment?